# Spring boot + spring boot security start error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm doing a MVC project with spring boot and spring security and jsp. I'm just training my spring and I have the same project running without spring boot. Currently I moved to springboot and when I try to start I get :

> 2020-05-09 17:28:38.521  INFO 21308 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
>   embedded WebApplicationContext 2020-05-09 17:28:38.527  INFO 21308 ---
>   [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6813 ms 2020-05-09
>   17:28:38.753  WARN 21308 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
>   Failed to determine a suitable driver class 2020-05-09 17:28:38.769 
>   INFO 21308 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2020-05-09 17:28:38.826  INFO 21308 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
>   no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

I have no idea what is happening.

application.properties

```
# JDBC properties
#
app.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
app.datasource.username=springstudent
app.datasource.password=springstudent

# Spring Data JPA properties
spring.data.jpa.repository.packages=com.crm.dao
spring.data.jpa.entity.packages-to-scan=com.crm.beans

#
# SECURITY JDBC properties
#
security.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_security_demo_bcrypt?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
security.datasource.username=springstudent
security.datasource.password=springstudent
security.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        // add a reference to our security data source

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("securityDataSource")
        private DataSource securityDataSource;


        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("aplicando configuracion");
            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/employees/showForm*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employees/save*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employees/delete").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/showMyLoginPage").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

        }


    }
```

Configuration:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"${spring.data.jpa.repository.packages}"})
public class DemoDataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app.datasource")
    public DataSource appDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.data.jpa.entity")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, DataSource appDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(appDataSource)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="security.datasource")
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your properties file...

Change `app.datasource.*` to `spring.datasource.*` like below..

```
# JDBC properties
#
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent
```

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

This error message gives hint that when Soring looks for database URL property.. (they have a fixed property name for it.. like `spring.datasource.*`) Or Else.. if you are using any embedded database like DB2 then it does not require any `url`/`username`/`password` only the dependency is enough.

In your case, it's not embedded database.. so the property name spring looks for, must be provided correctly.

Comment: Hello, doing so, the error is gone, but the custom configuration (DemoSecurityConfig) is not applied.

Comment: Hi, the error you posted was all about database connection issues only. Please provide more details on that.... or better ask a separate question on Stackoverflow (Community Recommended) as this will help different users.